# Rescue block did not run in rails migration script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have generated following migration:

```
class AddMarketStatusIdToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :market_status_id, :integer
  end
end
```

But it started raising following error at heroku:

```
20150816131733 AddMarketStatusIdToProducts: migrating =====================
-- add_column(:products, :market_status_id, :integer)
   (1.7ms)  ALTER TABLE "products" ADD "market_status_id" integer
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "products" ADD "market_status_id" integer
   (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
```

Error message is quite clear, so I used following Migration script instead:

```
class AddMarketStatusIdToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    begin
      add_column :products, :market_status_id, :integer
    rescue PG::UndefinedTable
      create_table :products do |t|
        t.float :price

        t.timestamps null: false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But still I am getting exactly same error message!! I don't understand, why my rescue code did not run?

Comment: Are you sure that `PG::UndefinedTable` is getting back to your code rather than a `StandardError`? Not certain but it looks like something inside Rails is catching the `PG::UndefinedTable` and raising a `StandardError` of its own. Looks to like you've made a mess of things with different migrations being run in different environments or migrations being added, run, and removed in only one environment and now you're trying to repair your mess. I'd clean up your development environment by hand so that you can start migrating all over again.

Comment: PS: Storing a price in a floating point value is madness, never do that.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for your comment. Yep, you got it right, I am trying to repair my mess. So resetting my development database and while migrating from beginning fixing where I hit error... like this.. will be the best way to fix this kind of mess? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why your rescue block is not running but I think that your error actually is this one `StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:` which is a `StandardError` which you can handle like this may be: `rescue StandardError => error`. But this is just a guess I don't know about this.

But the correct way to do the above is:

```
class AddMarketStatusIdToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if table_exists?("products")
      add_column :products, :market_status_id, :integer
    else
      create_table :products do |t|
        t.float :price
        t.integer :market_status_id
        t.timestamps null: false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rails has provided us methods `table_exists?` and `column_exists?` to do this. I have never used this but I know this can be done. So please check the syntax once as I am not 100% sure about the syntax.

Hope this helps.